# Mysql Error 2003-Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I use an Ubuntu server to host my php files , I am able to see my webpages but the problem arises when it tries to connect to mysql. I get the following error:

```
Database Login failed! Please make sure that the DB login credentials provided are correct
mysqlerror:Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.9.247.140' (111)
Database login failed!
```

Here is my login code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("10.9.247.140","root","password","gg");
```

THINGS I TRIED BEFORE POSTING HERE:

- I checked all the privileges and tested the credentials I used in my php files.
- Able to log into my database using PHPMyAdmin and Ubuntu Terminal.
- Tried using HeidiSQL to access the same table -FAILS
- Created a user ROOT with all privileges and `HOST-%(any)` - again unable to connect from php files and HeidiSQL.

Answer (score 3):

1). enable Remote Access

1.`nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

2.comment the quoted content `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` use # symbol

3.restart MySQL server

2). create a database

```
create database db_name;
```

3). Create user and grant PRIVILEGES

This assume you put the web server and mysql at the same IP.

```
CREATE USER 'user_name'@'10.9.247.140' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';

GRANT ALL ON db_name.* to 'user_name'@'10.9.247.140' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

mysql --host=10.9.247.140 --user=user_name --password=pwd db_name
```

If the web server is using another IP, replace the 'user_name'@'10.9.247.140' with the real one.